# Does vala have function static variables?

Tags: vala

Does Vala have function static variables?

By "function static variable" I mean a variable declared inside a function that keeps its value between invocations, like in the following c example:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void foo()
{
    int a = 10;
    static int sa = 10;

    a += 5;
    sa += 5;

    printf("a = %d, sa = %d\n", a, sa);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it doesn't.

In your example you can either use a global variable or wrap the function in a class and make the variable an attribute of that class.

The keyword `static` has a completely different meaning and is only used for class members that are not bound to an instance.

Comment: I'm not sure but, could it be possible to achieve the op static behaviour with **unowned** ? I just can't use global or the maintainer will cut my head off, i wish also it could be kept simple.

Comment: `unowned` doesn't help in this context.

Comment: You could use a closure to capture the state of a local variable, not sure how the compiler will handle the state in that case though.